# PhoneGap / Cordova scrollTo Ignored

Tags: ios, cordova, ios-simulator

I'm using Cordova 1.9.0 on iOS and loading an external site into the UIWebView container. Everything runs at it should however if you scroll down the page and click a link the next page loads at the same scroll position rather than at the top of the page.

I have been unable to force it to load the pages at the top so now I'm trying to use:

```
window.scrollTo( 0, 0 );
```

However this seems to be completely ignored when run in the simulator and on the phone whereas it works fine in Safari on the desktop.

Any help would be appreciated.